# Play Asset Delivery Android resource linking failed - Execution failed for task :app:linkDebugManifestForAssetPacks

Tags: java, android, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to build a soundboard app. I have lots of sounds to deploy so I decided to use Play Asset Delivery. I followed the instructions in the Google's guide.

1. I created an asset pack folder in the top level and named it sounds. This is how my project looks

   Project structure:
   [image]

This is the `build.gradle` file in the sounds directory

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.asset-pack'

assetPack {
packName = "sounds" // Directory name for the asset pack
dynamicDelivery {
    deliveryType = "[install-time]"
}
}
```

2. Updated my app build.gradle file

   ```
   android {
   .
   .
   .
   assetPacks = [":sounds"]
   }
   ```

and my settings.gradle file

```
include ':app'
include ':sounds'
```

3. Placed the assets in the sounds/src/main/assets

When I try to build the bundle I keep getting this error

Gradle Error:
[image]

This is the Manifest in the sounds folder

Manifest with errors:
[image]

I tried cleaning the project, invalidating caches and restarting but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending so many hours I managed to build the bundle successfully.

Simply remove brackets from your asset folder's build.gradle file

```
deliveryType = "install-time"
```

This is Google's example code for Play Asset Delivery

```
// In the asset pack’s build.gradle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.asset-pack'

assetPack {
    packName = "asset-pack-name" // Directory name for the asset pack
    dynamicDelivery {
        deliveryType = "[ install-time | fast-follow | on-demand ]"
    }
}
```

I thought  *deliveryType = "[install-time]"*  would be the correct syntax. After comparing my asset pack manifest with a dynamic feature's manifest I realized gradle produces a wrong dist attribute.

This is what i got for writing deliveryType with brackets

```
<dist:[install-time]/>
```

This is the correct syntax in the dynamic feature's manifest

```
<dist:on-demand />
```

Removing brackets did the trick. Hope it helps someone.